# BugSense (Mint Splunk) framework crashes

Tags: xcode, bugsense

As I'm using BugSense, lately I've noticed the following in the stacktrace:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib 0x36e0067a 0x36de0000 + 132730
1   Application -[SPLJSONModel toJSONStringWithKeys:] (in Application) (SPLJSONModel.m:1043) 
2   Application -[MintRequestWorker sendGnip:completionBlock:] (in Application) (MintRequestWorker.m:370) 
3   Application -[MintRequestJsonSerializer serializeEventToJsonForGnipWithAppEnvironment:] (in Application) (MintRequestJsonSerializer.m:56) 
4   Application __58-[MintRequestWorker closeSessionAsyncWithCompletionBlock:]_block_invoke (in Application) (MintRequestWorker.m:539) 
5   libdispatch.dylib 0x3750bbeb 0x37509000 + 11243
6   libdispatch.dylib 0x3751a9b1 0x37509000 + 72113
7   libdispatch.dylib 0x3751a395 0x37509000 + 70549
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x376c5b29 0x376c4000 + 6953
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x376c5718 0x376c4000 + 5912
```

And a quite similar error below:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x19b19b1e0 0x19b180000 + 111072
1   libsystem_c.dylib 0x19b10eb78 0x19b0ac000 + 404344
2   Application -[PLCrashReporter generateLiveReportWithThread:] (in Application) + 0 
3   CoreFoundation 0x185db12e4 0x185c8c000 + 1200868
```

Apparently, BugSense itself is causing an error.

Any similar experience so far? What could be the cause of this? I'm at most suspicious about the framework.

Thanks in advance for your hints!

Comment: downoad new mint splunk sdk updated for ios9

Comment: @mitulmarsonia Have the latest version compatible with iOS9 - version 4.4.1. However, the same problems emerge. Any hint or similar experience?

Comment: Try to remove this [[Mint sharedInstance] initAndStartSession:@"key"]; then try

Answer (score 0):

On the Build Settings tab under Linking, find Other Linker Flags and add "-ObjC" and "-all_load".

[Splunk Mint Documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintIOSSDK/5.1.x/DevGuide/Requirementsandinstallation)